# delete linux os booting choices from os choice menu

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot

I have a problem with a computer that had Linux OS installed (Ubuntu) a couple of times and after that, someone installed Windows XP. The OS choice menu now has one of the Ubuntu choices as default, some other Ubuntu choices following that, while the Windows one is the last. The only operating  system available is actually Windows, all the hard drive space has been formatted and converted to two NTFS partitions.

I would like to delete the (invalid) Ubuntu entries and leave only the Windows choice so that the user wouldn't have to make any choices in the booting process and hide the OS choice menu altogether if there's only one choice (Windows).

Any help would be much appreciated.
**Edit** I wasn't paying enough attention. I was in fact using the Grub loader. The fix was typing *fixmbr* at the recovery console, using a windows install cd. Thank you everybody for your help.

Comment: Are you using GRUB or the default Windows bootloader?

Comment: Sorry, it appears i'm using the GRUB loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm going to assume that the active bootloader is the Windows bootloader.  If this is the case, you can set the default OS by right-clicking on My Computer, choosing "Properties", selecting the "Advanced" tab, and choosing "Settings" in the "Startup and Recovery" section.

You could also try editing the boot.ini file via [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022).

Lastly, if the Windows bootloader is NOT the active bootloader, you'll need to follow [marcusw's instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/161369/delete-linux-os-booting-choices-from-os-choice-menu/161374#161374).

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet (considering that the Ubuntu systems no longer actually exist) would really be to simply boot up an Ubuntu cd and install a command line utility called "ms-sys" and use that to "Install a windows MBR" or in other words remove the boot menu. Just run `ms-sys help` after installing it and that will tell you what to do for your version of windows.